# SQL find word in string

Tags: sql, string, find

I have a string like that format:

`'%asdasasd\ngalaxy\n4198461841\nasdadadqd\n11111118181gals%'`

and i need to know is this string contains a word from column `mName` in `table1`:

[image]

In this case I need the output to be `galaxy`

Comment: Try something with the operator LIKE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not  know what database do you use but this will work in **Mysql** and **Oracle**:

```
select *
from table1
where instr('%asdasasd\ngalaxy\n4198461841\nasdadadqd\n11111118181gals%', mname) <> 0;
```

I have created a table called `test`
You use instr function to find a value from a column `mName` in the string if it exists then you show it.

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8b4db82064d72bf86fefca82e4d3c158)

Or as forpas suggested in his comment you can use like:

```
select * from table1
where '%asdasasd\ngalaxy\n4198461841\nasdadadqd\n11111118181gals%'
      like '%'||mname||'%'
```